# Update MySQL Table og_membership, how to then update Drupal without Clear All Cache

Tags: organic-groups, caching, database

New to Drupal and I can't figure this one out. My company wanted an external way of updating a User's group, I found that the groups were located in og_memebership and with a update

```
UPDATE og_membership SET gid = @gid WHERE etid= @uid
```

I am able to update all the appropriate rows in MySQL, however it doesn't update Drupal and the old group stays until I do a 'Flush all cache'. I even tried logging out and logging back in, using a different browser, different computer and all no go. I am somewhat afraid of updating the cache through code since I have never done this and/or worked with blobs.

Anyone have any suggestions by chance? (Using Drupal 7, and my Script is run vis C++, SSIS)

Thanks

EDIT: 
I did a grep to search for cache and found og_flush_caches , it used an array cache_entity_og_membership and cache_entity_og_membership_type ... after doing a select on both.. the two tables show up null. I will keep searching, but so far no luck with the cache

Comment: In basic terms you need to find the pattern the og module uses for that particular cache key, what cache table it uses, and then delete that row from the appropriate table (or if you're using a non-db cache backend, clear it from there instead). I'm not familiar with og so can't comment exactly what that might be, but searching through the module for `cache_set(` might help to shed some light